# Internal Server Error 500 when there should be "just" a php error

Tags: php, apache, internal

my friend ordered a VPS and we're having some issues with it.
The server responds with 500  Internal Server Error when there should be a php error telling me what's wrong.

For example I had this script:

```
<?php

echo 'hi';


?>
```

for testing and it was just for a test. Then I made some errors into it so that normally php would just throw some errors:

```
<?php

echo 'hi';
sdsd
sd

?>
```

But in our case the server now throws a 500 Internal Server error instead showing a small warning. I didn't change any file permission or anything that could cause this, I think it's the configuration.

Here i am posting the php.ini:

```
[Verisign Payflow Pro]
pfpro.defaultport = 443
pfpro.defaulttimeout = 30
pfpro.defaulthost = "test-payflow.verisign.com"

[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.max_persistent = -1

[Assertion]

[mSQL]
msql.allow_persistent = On
msql.max_persistent = -1
msql.max_links = -1

[Sybase]
sybase.max_links = -1
sybase.compatability_mode = Off
sybase.min_error_severity = 10
sybase.allow_persistent = On
sybase.min_message_severity = 10
sybase.max_persistent = -1

[gd]

[MySQL]
mysql.default_socket = 
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_password = 
mysql.default_port = 
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.default_user = 
mysql.default_host = 
mysql.trace_mode = Off
mysql.connect_timeout = 60

[COM]

[exif]

[Sybase-CT]
sybct.allow_persistent = On
sybct.max_persistent = -1
sybct.min_client_severity = 10
sybct.max_links = -1
sybct.min_server_severity = 10

[Session]
session.bug_compat_42 = 0
session.auto_start = 0
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.bug_compat_warn = 1
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.hash_function = 0
session.entropy_length = 0
session.serialize_handler = php
session.cookie_path = /
session.entropy_file = 
session.gc_probability = 1
session.cache_expire = 180
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.cookie_domain = 
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check = 
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "/tmp"
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5

[mbstring]

[Date]

[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl = 86400
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled = 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir = "/tmp"

[mail function]
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
smtp_port = 25
smtp = localhost

[PostgresSQL]
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.log_notice = 0
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.max_persistent = -1

[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off

[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0

[MySQLi]
mysqli.default_host = 
mysqli.default_pw = 
mysqli.reconnect = Off
mysqli.default_user = 
mysqli.default_socket = 
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.default_port = 3306

[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off

[Syslog]
define_syslog_variables = Off

[browscap]

[Informix]
ifx.max_links = -1
ifx.byteasvarchar = 0
ifx.max_persistent = -1
ifx.default_password = 
ifx.nullformat = 0
ifx.textasvarchar = 0
ifx.charasvarchar = 0
ifx.allow_persistent = On
ifx.blobinfile = 0
ifx.default_host = 
ifx.default_user = 

[FrontBase]

[PHP]
asp_tags = Off
include_path = ".:"
ignore_repeated_source = Off
variables_order = "EGPCS"
track_errors = Off
output_buffering = 4096
auto_globals_jit = On
doc_root = 
log_errors = On
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
auto_append_file = 
disable_classes = 
enable_dl = On
display_startup_errors = Off
user_dir = 
extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules"
register_argc_argv = Off
display_errors = On
open_basedir = "/var/www/vhosts/whatdate.info/httpdocs/:/tmp/"
allow_call_time_pass_reference = Off
safe_mode_exec_dir = 
default_socket_timeout = 60
register_globals = Off
unserialize_callback_func = 
y2k_compliance = On
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
expose_php = Off
log_errors_max_len = 1024
post_max_size = "16M"
report_memleaks = On
engine = On
memory_limit = "64M"
short_open_tag = On
max_execution_time = 60
safe_mode_include_dir = 
serialize_precision = 100
precision = 14
upload_max_filesize = "16M"
register_long_arrays = Off
safe_mode = "off"
zend.ze1_compatibility_mode = Off
zlib.output_compression = Off
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
default_mimetype = "text/html"
disable_functions = 
file_uploads = On
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
max_input_time = 60
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
error_reporting = E_ALL
safe_mode_gid = Off
auto_prepend_file = 
implicit_flush = Off
allow_url_fopen = On

[MSSQL]
mssql.compatability_mode = Off
mssql.allow_persistent = On
mssql.max_persistent = -1
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
mssql.min_message_severity = 10
mssql.max_links = -1
mssql.secure_connection = Off
```

can anybody tell me what's wrong or at least give a hint?

Thank you very much

Comment: `sdsd` is not a small warning but a parse error

Comment: They question stands, with display_errors on, why does the parse error not show?

Comment: @Matthias Dunnowa: for these types of questions, please add the tag related to the http/s server software you are using.  IE: apache|iis|etc.  "Server" and "internal" aren't really valid tags here.

Comment: Have you called your host's tech support?

Comment: I added it thanks for the notice. yeah will ask support about it, was curious if I could fix it myself to learn something out of it

Answer (score 1):

you should inspect your [error.log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#errorlog)

Also, wiki quotes

> 500 - generic error message, given when no more specific message is suitable

In my experience i have also encountered such issues with php files having permission of 777. try inspecting your php file's permission. if found 777 turn it into 755.

Once the php files have 777 permission, it is stopped and throws an error 500.